# Use youtube audio sequence with local video

Tags: api, youtube

Is it somehow possible to combine the audio sequence of a youtube video with another video?

The user enters a youtube url and uploads a local video. 
Now I want to combine his video with the audio sequence of the youtube url.

1. Is that legal?
2. Is it possible? Data API?
3. How? Do I need to download the youtube video to my server first?
4. Thank you.

Comment: 1. Legal depends on jurisdiction, licensing of the videos, fair use exemptions, and any number of other things. Asking "is that legal" is like asking "is meat tasty" - the answer is "maybe, it depends on the person and preparation..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is using `cvlc` or some other script to download the youtube video, then `ffmpeg` or `avcodec` command line tool to take the audio track from one videoclip, the video track from the other and combine them into one output stream.

As of the legality, you cannot do it as a paid or sponsored service for sure, but this is out of the scope of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you. You got a link with a tutorial / manual about cvlc, can't find one?

Comment: I am quite sure it is possible, although some folks on `#videolan` could not tell me how. Nevermind, use [this](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) script instead.